# An unhandled exception : Two Hubs must not share the same name

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

What is this error?
In the first calling this code:

`SignalRInvoker Invoker = new SignalRInvoker GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GeneralHub>().Clients);`

And the funny exception is :

> Two Hubs must not share the same name. 'SM.GUI.Common.Remouting.GeneralHub, SM.GUI.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'SM.GUI.Common.Remouting.GeneralHub, SM.GUI.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' both share the name 'generalHub'.

Comment: I got the same error while using Code Contracts, once I disabled code contracts everything worked fine. I think it has something to do with proxies being created for the your hubs.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I needed to move the hub class out of the app_code folder.

Comment: I had the same problem here with a Web Application.  Just renamed the folder to App_Start to follow new standards

Answer (score 0):

This error can be  caused by not publishing the Hub correctlly,

Take a look at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2935 it deals with the same error.

Comment: i saw that before, and it doesn't helpful, anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: i thing there is a bug in calling "GlobalHost.ConnectionManager" on some threads, and i had to change my programming methods

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I accidentally had 2 different .dll's in the bin folder of my web project, with one of them being an old .dll which happened to also contain the same named hub in it.  When deploying to IIS I think the hub auto discovery process found the hubs in both .dlls.  As soon as I just deleted the old .dll I worked fine.